# Compile C++ code to standalone application .app

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

How can I compile c++ code to .app? 
I've created console app in XCode, after compilation created xcodeproj file.
But I need .app extention.

Additional description:
I have Delphi for OS X, and C++ application. These apps are connected via socket. So all is going good. When i was testing I had opened c++ app in XCode and Run it. But now I need c++ app would be opened automatically by delphi. 
So, I had succes to open xcodeproj file, but it opens terminal window. 
I've searched for info in inthernet and found that application must not be created as console app. Console apps can't be compiled to .app extention by XCode(if it can tell me the way please).

So, please tell me how resolve.

UPDATE:
Maybe i must recreate project as GUI project. So how rebuild to gui proj from c++ code

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode, try the Archiving window.
This should let you save your compiled application as `.app` on OS X.

More Info:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2215/_index.html

Comment: I've tried this. Archiving can't create .app for console application as final. Anyway i'm checking your link.